# Using jQuery connected, sortable lists, how can I prevent 3 ajax calls here...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

#### Using jQuery 1.4 and jQueryUI 1.8

I have a table structure with 3 columns, each of which is a "linked" sortable list.

I would like to send an AJAX update to my server, that only contains information for the given column (if any items were moved), and only for the *two* given columns if an item was moved between columns.

To expound: if **List A, Item 1** moves only to a new position within **List A**, I have no reason to send a request to update any list order but **List A**, which can be accomplished via a callback on `update`. Easy.

However, if I move **List A, Item 1** to **List B**, I would like to send as few requests as possible (1, possibly 2) to update the ordering for the given lists. However, when using callbacks `receive` and `remove`, `update` is always *also* called.

My first thought was to use `update` and/or `remove`, find the original list, and update both. But with `update` being called first, that would be cause *at least* one extra ajax request to the server.

If I use *only* `update` and just watch for `ui.sender` in the callback, I would still be sending 2 requests, because the first update fires for the list that's now missing an item (I have to assume it was only resorted with no `ui.sender`) and then the second update fires with a `ui.sender`, where I would update the old and new lists.

I can't *not* use `update`, or I'll miss items that are moved within their own list.

How should I approach this? What have I overlooked?

Comment: Same problem. Did you find a solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890923/jquery-ui-sortable-and-two-connected-lists

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time on this and was dissapointed there was no answer here!!

But I eventually figured it out.

It works by checking the parent UL to see if the item actually exists in the list that its updating.

```
var sortorder = ui.item.index();

if(this.children[sortorder] != null 
&& this.children[sortorder].innerHTML == ui.item.context.innerHTML) //you could use an id here.
{
  // do stuff like update the sort order of the record in the database via ajax.
}
```

what is it with stack overflow and the code boxes that are only one line? 
Does anyone ele have this problem??
I'm using IE 6

Cheers,
Nigel.