# jQuery sortable two lists on opposite parts of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two lists on opposite parts of the page. So when i drag an element from the left list and cross the middle of the page with the mouse, i would like the dragged element to be appended to the right list, and vice versa.
How can i achieve that?
here is a snippet to show how it looks like

CODEPEN:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbMyLo

```
//
```

**EDIT:**
So far i've did this, which works, but I can't see the dragged element.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?   (be more specific) -- is it just that you haven't sorted it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890923/jquery-ui-sortable-and-two-connected-lists   I was able to get it to work with a few changes to your html.  https://jsfiddle.net/9tsgp2af/

Comment: @devlin I already have that working. I just don't want that the user will have to drag it across the whole page, just to the middle, where it will change the list it belongs to